# Сортировка любого многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

> Задание: Разработать функцию, получающую на вход любой многомерный массив и сортирующую этот массив в порядке убывания/возрастания конечных результатов или сумм. (Подсказка функция `is_array($array)` определяет массив ли это)

```
    function arrSum($arr) {
  $sum = 0;

  forEach($arr as $value) {

    if (is_array($value))

      $sum += arrSum($value);
    else

      $sum += $value;
  }

  return $sum;
}
```

Пока ничего лучше чем нахождения суммы всего массива через рекурсию не нашел.

Comment: Для читаемости кода и логики, я бы назвал функцию arraySort) Вам надо создать два индекса `i`,`j` и пробегаться двумя циклами.

Comment: да, название не в тему).  функция у меня должна принимать массив любой размерности, может и 10-ти мерную. двух индексов хватит?

Comment: А что в вашем понимании 10 мерный?

Comment: имею ввиду массив сосотоящий из массивов, массивов и т.д. 10-ти мерный даже не могу представить